# Protect home (webserver's) dynamic ip from reverse DNS issue

Tags: apache, dns, reverse, mod-proxy

this is my first question here =)

I'm setting my webserver at home (trying both apache and nginx) and I've found that you can easily get and use free dynamic dns (sub) domain to make your server available not only with your home ip that would be changed next time after disconnect and connect to the internet. Actually I've made it working and it's great..

But the problem is that my personal unique data (account id/machine name) could be retrieved with reverse dns look up and I can not hide my real ip that is attached to server.

You can use proxy while browsing the internet, but how to proxy your web server (apache) that have free dyn dns (sub) domain?

I've already tried to create VirtualHost configurations, also with the use of proxy modules (mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http, mod_proxy_html) and additionally with proxifier tool, but no luck.

Some people say that it is possible to hide ip with nginx, but I never used to work with nginx. Still believe it is also possible with Apache, just can't figure it out.

I'm using private proxy in format [proxyip:port]. I must attach it everytime to my home ip to make it work. Maybe it's better to get login/password auth proxy, but at first I should find the way how to use it with web server.

Is there anyone who have luck with it? Can you explain, please, the proper config for apache? Currently I'm using version 2.4.

Many thanks and have a good day!

Comment: You cannot hide the IP of a server that users are connecting to.

Comment: Sure, I understand that. But is it possible to run web-server with proxy as a main ip?

Comment: No. The type of web proxy you are using can only proxy *outbound* requests, not incoming ones.

Comment: Thx, looks like half of the answer! So I need user:pass auth proxy? I can have one. What next should I do? Configure it as reverse proxy?

Comment: Just don't know if I need to install additional web server and somehow link it with the main web server and auth proxy. The info that I've found doesn't explain that, only basically.